# Can't understand logcat messages and find NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, contacts

I'm developing a Contacts Manager to use in a real application, but I got stuck in a problem, and I can't solve it.

Here is what I got in LogCat while running the app:

```
02-28 15:18:31.310: D/AndroidRuntime(845): Shutting down VM 02-28 15:18:31.310: W/dalvikvm(845): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a1db90)`
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845): Process: br.com.agendadecontatos, PID: 845
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.agendadecontatos/br.com.agendadecontatos.LerContatos}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at br.com.agendadecontatos.LerContatos.onCreate(LerContatos.java:34)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
02-28 15:18:31.320: E/AndroidRuntime(845):  ... 11 more
02-28 15:18:40.440: I/Process(845): Sending signal. PID: 845 SIG: 9
```

I already tried to solve one problem per time, but I can't find any `NullPointerException` in my code. These are the only ones who appears to be null.

```
Cursor C_Contatos =this.ctx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

Cursor C_Telefones = this._ctx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " =" +
                        " " + _IDContato, null, null);
```

EDIT.: Here is the LerContatos code with the OnCreate method:

```
package br.com.agendadecontatos;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class LerContatos extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ListView listaPessoas = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        List<ProvedorDeContatos> ListaContatos = new ArrayList<ProvedorDeContatos>();

        Contatos Contato = new Contatos(this);

        ListaContatos = Contato.getContatos();       

        ArrayAdapter<ProvedorDeContatos> adapter = 
                new ArrayAdapter<ProvedorDeContatos>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ListaContatos);   
        listaPessoas.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button botaoAdicionar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdicionar);

        botaoAdicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {

                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setClass(LerContatos.this,
                                    CameraAndroid.class);

                            startActivity(intent);

                            finish();
                        }
                    });

    }       
}
```

Thanks for helping! I found a way to recreate the adapter.

Comment: It seems that your problem is in the file LerContatos.java on line 34

Comment: What is line 34 `LerContatos.java`. that is where you have nullpointerexcpetion

Comment: May be your **ctx** variable is null.

Comment: @PiyushGupta He is also using "ctx" in one line, and "_ctx" in another. Perhaps that is a mistake as well.

Comment: Can you post `LerContatos` class's onCreate() method's code ?

Comment: Hey guys, I updated my post with the main.java code. How can I solve the mistake with the ctx variable? They're independent, aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the first line in the stacktrace that is related to your code.  It will tell you the line in the where the exception occurred (in this case, looks like: *LerContatos.java:34* )

Go to this line in your code, and look at the variables accessed here.  There is one that has not been instantiated before you are using it.  This means, the value of that variable in NULL at this point, and is what the error is about.

Comment: Does the blank lines count as one?

Comment: @LeoS to turn on line numbers in eclipse go to "Windows” > “Preference” > “General” > “Editors” > “Text Editors” and check on the “Show line numbers” option.

Comment: Yes, but your IDE should show line numbers (or allow you to navigate directly to a particular line - it is Cntrl-L in Eclipse).

Comment: Oh great! I didn't know about this hotkey. It's on "listaPessoas.setAdapter(adapter);"

Comment: How can I substitute it?

Comment: Either your listaPessoas object is not initialized or your adapter object.  Ensure both of these have been created before accessing them here.  (This is by far the single most common error in Java)

Comment: Thanks guys! I found another way to create this adapter.